In the ECMAScript spec, what are the semantic rules of VarScopedDeclarations and VarDeclaredNames of a non-empty block statement?
I'm studying the ECMAScript spec to find out what the expected behavior of vars statements inside a block is according to the spec:


function test() {
    console.log('before block', bar);
    {
      console.log('in block before declaration', bar);
      var bar = 30;
      console.log('in block after declaration', bar); 
    }
    console.log('after block', bar);
}

test();



I know that var is not block-scoped. But I'm curious about how the spec uses concrete definitions of steps to achieve it.
I've read the semantics of the DeclarationInstantiation of function and global. They take static semantics VarDeclaredNames and VarScopedDeclarations of function body or script to create bindings to the environment record. But I can't find the definition in these static semantics of how to deal with the block statement with the nested StatementList. The spec only defined the production for empty block (without any statement):

Or should Block: { StatementList } be seen as a StatementList directly?

But in 14.2 it is defined as a single statement?
I found other semantics include instructions for the production   Block { statementList }, so I expect to see something like:
Block: { StatementList }
  1. Return VarDeclaredNames of StatementList.

Here's the example defined instructions of production Block { statementList } in evaluation operation:


AFAIK blocks have no effect on var declarations. They're function-scoped, not block-scoped like the ES6 let and const declarations.

@Barmar Yeah, I agree. So I expect to see something like "VarDeclaredNames: Block { StatementList }: 1. Return VarDeclaredNames of StatementList." But I couldn't find that in the spec.

There's this note at the top of § 14.3.2. Variable Statement: "A var statement declares variables that are scoped to the running execution context's VariableEnvironment. Var variables are created when their containing Environment Record is instantiated and are initialized to undefined when created. [...]" Is that what you are looking for?

Just read the question thoroughly. I am not going to repeat it. In short, it is a question about the ECMA Script language specification, and a seemingly missing part in the specification of variable declaration in the context of syntax directed analysis. It is certainly not about 7 tasks which really are procedure steps in the context of runtime semantics, which is not what their question is about, but is given as comparison.

Please [edit] your post to replace all those images of text with actual text. The markdown supports it just fine.

@wahwahwah Maybe my answer helps you understand what the question was asking about


I expect to see something like:
Block: { StatementList }
  1. Return VarDeclaredNames of StatementList.


Your expectation is well-founded, but it would be rather boring and arduous to define VarDeclaredNames for every single syntactic element, doing nothing other than recursing into its descendant element.
So the spec authors decided to only provide an implicit definition for these Syntax-Directed Operations:

Unless explicitly specified otherwise, all chain
productions
have an implicit definition for every operation that might be applied
to that production's left-hand side nonterminal. The implicit
definition simply reapplies the same operation with the same
parameters, if any, to the chain
production's
sole right-hand side nonterminal and then returns the result.

See also the example following that paragraph.

Thank you! This is what I'm looking for. The definition of "chain production" and how its semantic rule is implicitly defined explain how to handle the production Block: { StatementList }.

The only way you can make this better is to provide a simple example

@wahwahwah The example can be found in the spec, I just didn't want to quote the entire chapter when a link does suffice
